# Delete this architecture and Undefined Behaviour

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, delete-operator

```
#include <memory>

struct B;    

struct A
{
     std::shared_ptr<B> field1_;
     A():field1_ (std::make_shared<B>()){}
};

template<class A>
struct B: std::enable_shared_from_this<B<A>>
{
     A *field1_; 

     void stop()
     {
        delete field1_; //~= delete this
     }

     A* start()
     {
         field1_ = new A(shared_from_this());
         return field1_;
     }
};

int main()
{
    A * reftoA = nullptr;

    {
        std::shared_ptr<B<A>> b = std::make_shared<B<A>>();
        reftoA = b->start();
    }

    reftoAa->field1_->stop();
}
```

I have a bug in production and I am wondering if the above code could corrupt the HEAP or lead to an Undefined Behaviour.

EDIT:
I have change the above code to be closer to my real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting an object from within one of its own methods is a very common technique when done deliberately and carefully. Many older reference-counting designs work that way, e.g. COM and derivatives like the Mozilla codebase. See: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/delete-this.html for advice.

But in this case it looks like a kind of accidental aliasing. Struct `B` appears to act partially like the "owner" of the object in `field1_`, thus giving it the right to delete it, and then you play an evil trick on it.

This being C++, it's not actually possible to tell whether this will lead to undefined behaviour without seeing the source of a complete program.

Answer (score 2):

That code shouldn't even compile because of

```
void setA(A* a):field1_(a){}
```

which isn't valid.

Also, since you're already using smart pointers, why keep `A *field1_;` in `B`?

Comment: "why keep A *field1_; in B?": because I need to access some A properties with a B reference.

Comment: @Guillaume07 as in, why not use a smart pointer for that member?

Comment: In fact I'm remember I do it because I don't know how to force the destructor of a shared_ptr pointed object to be call ( in case the reference counter equal 0)

Comment: @Guillaume07: The object is deleted normally (i.e. the destructor will be called) when the reference count reaches 0, unless you very explicitly avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a death penalty for **production** code like this one.

you call `B::func` which destroys the `A` it holds the pointer to and then in your `main` you delete the `A` again. What did you expect?

Comment: SORRY. I have edited my code, I have made a mistake in the first code i have posted.